# d3.js want to change node style on dragend

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3.js graph that allows the user to click and drag nodes around. Once they drag a node around, I'm considering it "fixed". Once it gets fixed I want to visually show the difference between nodes that are fixed and ones that aren't by changing the stroke for the node to a different color.

However, I don't know where to put in the logic for changing the stroke width. Right now, I put the logic when the circle is initially drawn, but it doesn't get updated after a node is dragged. Where should I put my logic check and style change?

Here is my code. Notice the `.style` change at the end of the `node.append("circle")`

```
d3.dsv(",", "board_games.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    source: d.source,
    target: d.target,
    value: +d.value
  }
}).then(function(data) {

  var links = data;

  var nodes = {};

  // compute the distinct nodes from the links.
  links.forEach(function(link) {
      link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
      link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
  });

  var width = 1200,
      height = 700;

  var force = d3.forceSimulation()
      .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
      .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).distance(100))
      .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
      .force("x", d3.forceX())
      .force("y", d3.forceY())
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-250))
      .alphaTarget(1)
      .on("tick", tick);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  // add the links
  var path = svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(links)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; });

  // define the nodes
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(force.nodes())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) {
         d.weight = 5;
         var minRadius = 10;
         return minRadius + (d.weight * 2);
       })
       .style("stroke", function(d){ if(d.fixed == true) {return 'gray'} else {return 'green'} });

    // add the curvy lines
  function tick() {
      path.attr("d", function(d) {
          var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
              dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
              dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
          return "M" +
              d.source.x + "," +
              d.source.y + "A" +
              dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " +
              d.target.x + "," +
              d.target.y;
      });

      node.attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      });
  };

  function dragstarted(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
      d.fx = d.x;
      d.fy = d.y;
  };

  function dragged(d) {
      d.fx = d3.event.x;
      d.fy = d3.event.y;
  };

  function dragended(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0);
      d.fixed = true;
      if (d.fixed == true) {
          d.fx = d.x;
          d.fy = d.y;
      }
      else {
          d.fx = null;
          d.fy = null;
      }
  };

}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

My csv looks like this:

```
source,target,value
Dork Tower,Nur Peanuts!,0
Dork Tower,Hepta,1
Snake Pit,Lucky Captain,0
Snake Pit,Alien Wars,0
Snake Pit,Full Moon Jacket,1
Dork Tower,Crystal Faire,1
Buffy the Vampire Slayer,Twixt,1
Buffy the Vampire Slayer,Hepta,1
Abduction,Leipzig,0
Dork Tower,Astro Drive,0
Abduction,Snake Pit,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `stroke` attribute right after `append("circle")`, what is done is done. The stroke color will be the one you set in that moment, i.e. `d.fixed !== true` and the stroke is green.

The right way to change the stroke color once dragend,

```
  function dragended(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0);
        d.fixed = true;
        if (d.fixed == true) {
              d.fx = d.x;
              d.fy = d.y;
        }
        else {
              d.fx = null;
              d.fy = null;
        }
        d3.select(this) // `this` is the node where drag happend
          .select("circle")
          .style("stroke", "grey");
    };
```

[a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/3TlMS1a5O34pf8JK?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview)